# undefined method 'every'

Tags: ruby-1.9.3, whenever

Trying to use the [whenever ruby gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever), however (no pun intended) errors occur every time  something is run:

```
1.9.3-p0 :001 > require 'whenever'
     => true 
1.9.3-p0 :002 > every 1.minutes do 
1.9.3-p0 :003 >     puts 'hi'
1.9.3-p0 :004?>   end
NoMethodError: undefined method `every' for main:Object
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/rudolph9/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I am running `Mac OS 10.7.3`, `Ruby 1.9.3`, and `Whenever v0.7.3`.  Is this a cron job issue with OSX?  What exactly the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whenever gem is not meant to be called directly like that. The blocks that you want to execute go into a schedule file (`config/schedule.rb` by default) that recognizes the DSL for cron-like tasks.

You can preview how your commands will be converted to the crontab by running the `whenever` command within the directory. Then to commit the jobs to your crontab, use

```
whenever --write-crontab
```